# How to store numbers from a XMM register into a char array within an asm loop -

Tags: c++, assembly, sse, simd

I have an xmm register holding four 32bit numbers within it.

`XMM4 = 00000035000000350000003500000035`

I have a loop which calculates these numbers over and over again and I then need to store them in an array somehow. How can i use asm to store each individual number from the XMM register, on each iteration of the loop?

Edit:

I have tried creating a char array outside of my __asm block like so: `char numbers[20];`
and then I've tried to move my registery values into it using `movdqa [numbers], xmm4`. This works for the first iteration of the loop, but I have no idea how to increment the index of the array on sequential iterations.

Edit2: Here is my code

```
    __m128i stuff = _mm_setr_epi32 ( 87, 137, 202, 222 );

    __m128i zeros = _mm_setr_epi32 ( 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 );

    __m128i fives = _mm_setr_epi32 ( 0x5, 0x5, 0x5, 0x5 );

    __m128i fortyEights = _mm_setr_epi32 ( 0x30, 0x30,0x30, 0x30 );

    __m128i magicNumber = _mm_setr_epi32 ( 0x66666667, 0x66666667, 0x66666667, 0x66666667 );

        __asm { 
                movdqa      xmm0, stuff         //Move data into xmm0
                movdqa      xmm1, magicNumber   //Move magic numbers into xmm1
                movdqa      xmm2, xmm0          //Copy data into xmm2
                vpcmpeqb    xmm2, xmm0, xmm2    //Compare data against zeros
                je          bail            //if data is all zeros then bail

    nextdigit:  pmulhw      xmm2, xmm1          //Multiply data in xmm2 by the magic numbers in xmm1
                psrad       xmm2, 2             //Divide [wip]data by 4 
                movdqa      xmm3, fives         //Copy the fives into xmm3
                pmullw      xmm3, xmm2          //Multiply [wip]data in xmm2 by the fives in xmm3
                paddd       xmm3, xmm3          //Multiply the [wip]data by 2
                movdqa      xmm4, xmm0          //Copy the original into xmm4
                psubd       xmm4, xmm3          //Subtract the [wip]data from the original data
                paddd       xmm4, fortyEights   //Add 48 to the [wip]data in xmm4 in order to get the ascii value

    // HERE IS WHERE I WANT TO SAVE THE VALUES TO AN ARRAY

                comiss      xmm0, zeros
                jne         nextdigit
bail:
                mov         eax, 0
    }
```

Comment: show us your code and you will receive help.

Comment: If you're doing this in C++, why use use intrinsics instead of inline assembly?

Comment: @Mysticial: ITYM "why *not* use intrinsics..." ?

Comment: Dammit, too late to edit my comment. Yes, that's what I meant, "Why *not* use intrinsics?"

Comment: I've edited my post with the code.

Comment: @BitBank I have added my code, any chance this helps?

Answer (score 0):

Use one of general purpose registers for index like:

```
  movdqa [oword ptr numbers + edx], xmm4      //Store xmm4 to numbers array
  add     edx, 16                              //Increment index
```

Comment: Hi @GJ., thanks for your answer. When I place your segment of code into the code above where it shows // HERE IS WHERE... the error I get is illegal type on PTR operator in 'context'

Comment: @Ste Prescott: Sorry, use `OWORD` PTR in c++

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When i do this however, the register values are appended onto the end of the array each loop, and I end up with a bunch of '0's in between each character. Ideally, what I want is to increment and index so that I an control which locations in the array are populated. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: @Ste Prescott: As I understand You have array which is 16 byte aligned and each member is long 16 bytes or four 32bit numbers. So if `edx` is 0 than you will address first member of array, if you add 16 with `add     edx, 16` instruction to `edx` than index point to second member and so on!

Answer (score 0):

There is so much wrong with this code.  I have no idea what you're even trying to do, but these are all big problems:

- you want to store just a character or two out of the bottom byte of a 16B register?  Why did you need a vector at all?
- `pcmpeqb` generates a mask of 0 or 0xff bytes, and doesn't set flags for `jcc`.  (use SSE4.1 `PTEST` for that).
- `comiss      xmm0, zeros`  does a *floating point* compare on the low 4 bytes of xmm0, which is holding integer data.  (`ss` = scalar single-precision).  I'm not sure what happens when the integer data happens to be `NaN`.  compare-for-equality with zero is the only comparison that has any hope of working.
- you can use `_mm_set1_epi32(0x66666667)` to broadcast.

Throw away all your current code, and start again with intrinsics for the whole thing.  Check out some of the resources at https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info